# Django 1.7 synchronize unmigrated apps

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

I started my model:

myapp.models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field_a = models.FloatField()
    field_c = models.FloatField()
```

Then ran `./manage.py migrate` on my new project and it was all good:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: myapp
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table myapp_mymodel
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Then I changed my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field_a = models.FloatField()
    field_b = models.FloatField()
    field_c = models.FloatField()
```

I ran `./manage.py migrate` again and nothing happened.

```
(project)$ ./manage.py migrate 
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: myapp
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I'm wondering what I need to do to make my new app migrate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ack, answered my own question.

What I needed to do was run:

```
./manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

Answer (score 4):

If this had been happening even if you had run the **makemigrations** command, you need to check if the **__initial__.py** empty file is present in the migrations folder. I had an incidence once when I had created migrations by running on a testing remote server and even though I had copied all created migrations to my code, I had forgotten to copy the placeholder empty file that helps the migrate command identify apps that have migrations to run.

Hope it helps someone.